# Check in JavaScript whether the code is running in a WinStore (WinJS) application

Tags: javascript, winjs

I'm developing a JS library that can be used in both Windows Store (WinJS) applications and in "regular" HTML/JS apps. One of the dependencies that I'm using (loading it dynamically) has two different SDKs, one for WinJS apps and one for "regular" web sites, so I'll need to know whether I'm running in a WinJS app to load the correct one.

I can try to find out whether some Windows-specific library exists (something like the code below), but I'm wondering if there is a "cleaner" way to figure out the environment in which the code is running. Is there such a way to tell that?

```
function isWinJS() {
    return typeof Windows === 'object' &&
        typeof Windows.UI === 'object' &&
        typeof Windows.UI.Popups === 'object' &&
        typeof Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog === 'function';
}
```

Comment: How can `Windows.UI` be an object and a function?

Comment: @Dendromaniac, fixed that, it was a copy/paste error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace detection is how WinJS determines whether it's running on Windows or the Web. I suggest taking a look at how it approaches these matters on a systematic basis. You could do this with the code on https://github.com/winjs/winjs (current versions), or instead look at WinJS 1.0 or 2.0 as used only on Windows, because the detection there is somewhat simpler. In those versions, the detection was needed because WinJS could be loaded into a Webview or web context in the app where WinRT wasn't available. One example I know of is implementing the WinJS sessionState object.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me to the right place. `WinJS.Utilities.hasWinRT` was the function I was looking for.